Proof about formulas to find oblique asymptotes
Theorem. Let be $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ a function and consider $y=mx+q$ with $m,q\in \mathbb{R}, \space m\ne 0$. The curve $y=mx+q$ is an oblique asymptote for $f$ iff $\lim_{x\to +\infty}[f(x)-(mx+q)]=0$.
My attempt to the proof.
If $\lim_{x\to +\infty}[f(x)-(mx+q)]=0$, then $\lim_{x\to +\infty}f(x)=\lim_{x\to +\infty}(mx+q)$.
The RHS is not zero, so it follows that
$$\lim_{x\to +\infty}\frac{f(x)}{mx+q}=1$$
This proves that $f(x)\sim(mx+q)$ for $x\to +\infty$.
Is it right? The vice versa it's pretty much the same reasoning.

What's your definition of asymptote?

In real analysis, an asymptote for $x\to x_0$ is a line that approximates the graph of $f$ in a neighborhood of $x_0$. In particular, an oblique asymptote is a line of the type $mx+q$ that approximates the graph of $f$ for $x\to \pm \infty$. My goal is to justify a little bit why the condition above is necessary and sufficient.

This does not seem a rigorous definition; $f\sim mx+q$ does not imply $mx+q$ is an asymptote

Okay...you're right. What can I use to prove that?

What definition can I use?

One definition is: $mx+q$ is an asymptote for $f$ if $f(x)=mx+q+o(1)$

See Formula for Oblique Asymptotes (especially my comment there) AND Using Derivatives to Prove Slant Asymptotes AND Proof about $f$ with slant asymptotes.
